# Linear Regression with symbolic x-coordinates

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have been having difficulty with this problem for a few days now so I'm hoping you can come to my aid.

I am trying to create a line of linear regression for a very small chart using `pgfplots`. Unfortunately my x-axis has symbolic x-coordinates and the compiler does not seem to like that at all for linear regression.

The plot works fine without the linear regression line but as soon as I add it everything goes to hell in a hand basket.

```
 83 \begin{figure}[h]
 84         \centering
 85         \begin{tikzpicture}
 86                 \begin{axis}[
 87                         title=Wavelength vs. Stopping Voltage,
 88                         xlabel={Wavelength},
 89                         ylabel={Stopping Voltage (Volts)},
 90                         symbolic x coords={Yellow, Green, Blue, Violet, U.V.}
 91                         ]
 92 
 93                         \addplot table {lab3.data};
 94                         \addplot table [
 95                                 symbolic x coords={Yellow, Green, Blue, Violet, U.V.},
 96                                 y={create col/linear regression={y=Voltage}}] {lab3.data};
 97 
 98                 \end{axis}
 99         \end{tikzpicture}
100 \end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{..}` and ending with `\end{document}`. And please remove the line number from the code (otherwise somebody who wants to help you has to do it).

Answer (score 3):

Since you did not provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), I'm making a guess about the format of your `.data` file:

```
Yellow  0
Green   1
Blue    2
Violet  3
U.V.    3
```

I create this using the `filecontents` package at the top of my example code. I used the filename `lab3-paul.data` so that it doesn't overwrite your real data file. :-)

The main issue here is that `pgfplots` needs some sort of numerical value for the x-coordinate in order to perform the calculations for a linear regression. If modifying your data file is an option, you could add a numerical x-value column (could be light wavelength in nanometer for your case, for instance, but it really doesn't matter). If this is an option, use the symbolic x-coordinate for plotting and the numerical x-coordinate for the regression.

For the remainder of this answer, I assume that modifying the data file is not an option. We can create a dummy column with some numerical value to use during the regression, but we have to fall back to the more sophisticated tools available directly at the `pgfplotstable` level. (`pgfplots` has an interface to only a limited set of capabilities via `\addplot table {...}`.)

The first step is to load the data, with

```
\pgfplotstableread{lab3-paul.data}\loadedtable
```

Now we can refer to our table as `\loadedtable` (this name is arbitrary) from this point forward.

Next, set up the created column:

```
\pgfplotstableset{create on use/xnum/.style={create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow}}}
```

This will create a column called `xnum` (again, arbitrary name) that will be created on use (that is, whenever queried in a `pgfplots`/`pgfplotstable` command). The column's value is simply the current row index.

For the first plot (of the original data), nothing needs to change, but since we've already loaded the data into `\loadedtable`, we might as well use that instead of loading it again from the file:

```
\addplot table {\loadedtable};
```

Then, for the regression line, we only need to specify that we want to use our calculated column `xnum` for the x-value for the regression calculations:

```
\addplot table [y={create col/linear regression={x=xnum}}] {\loadedtable};
```

In the complete code below, I've also added some legend entries for clarity:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{lab3-paul.data}
Yellow  0
Green   1
Blue    2
Violet  3
U.V.    3
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\pgfplotstableread{lab3-paul.data}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstableset{create on use/xnum/.style={create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  legend pos=south east,
  title=Wavelength vs. Stopping Voltage,
  xlabel={Wavelength},
  ylabel={Stopping Voltage (Volts)},
  symbolic x coords={Yellow, Green, Blue, Violet, U.V.}
]
  \addplot table {\loadedtable};
  \addlegendentry{Data};
  \addplot table [y={create col/linear regression={x=xnum}}] {\loadedtable};
  \addlegendentry{Regression};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]